# Does anyone know why my tests are stuck in queue with selenium grid?

Tags: selenium-grid

My tests are getting stuck in queue and are not starting.

Queue (1)
{"browserName":"chrome","browserVersion":"106","goog:chromeOptions":{"args":["--disable-dev-shm-usage","--no-sandbox","start-maximized"]},"platformName":"WINDOWS"}

Does anyone know why this would happen?

I am running Selenium grid through batch files.

Hub:
java -jar selenium-server-4.5.0.jar hub

Node:
java -jar "C:\AutomationEnv\selenium-server-4.5.0.jar" --detect-drivers true

The env path is set and the chromedriver is placed in the directory. When I launch http://localhost:4444/ I can view Selenium grid with chrome node.

I am using c#. Here is the connection for the driver with driveroptions.

```
            var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.PlatformName = "Windows";
            chromeOptions.BrowserVersion = "106";
            chromeOptions.AddArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
            chromeOptions.AddArguments("--no-sandbox");
            chromeOptions.AddArguments("start-maximized");

            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), chromeOptions);
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
```

Answer (score 0):

New Session Queue

Clear New Session Queue
New Session Request Queue holds the new session requests. To clear the queue, use the cURL command enlisted below. Clearing the queue rejects all the requests in the queue. For each such request, the server returns an error response to the respective client. The result of the clear command is the total number of deleted requests.

In the Standalone mode, the Queue URL is the Standalone server address.

In the Hub-Node mode, the Queue URL is the Hub server address.

```
cURL --request DELETE 'http://localhost:4444/se/grid/newsessionqueue/queue' --header 'X-REGISTRATION-SECRET: <secret>'
```

In the fully distributed mode, the Queue URL is New Session Queue server address.

```
cURL --request DELETE 'http://localhost:5559/se/grid/newsessionqueue/queue' --header 'X-REGISTRATION-SECRET: <secret>'
```

If no registration secret has been configured while setting up the Grid, then use

```
cURL --request DELETE 'http://<URL>/se/grid/newsessionqueue/queue' --header 'X-REGISTRATION-SECRET;'
```

[Selenium Documentation - Endpoints](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/grid/advanced_features/endpoints/)